# Unable to run emulator: AVD 'Nexus_5X_API_28'

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have 8GB RAM and there are a lot of installed programs on my hard drive. I have only 2GB remaining on my C: drive.

Everything was running fine until I installed "Bluestack", now I get the following error:

> ERROR: Not enough disk space to run AVD 'Nexus_5X_API_28'. Exiting..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a good time to sit down and do some spring cleaning on your hard drive.

Also if you need to increase the RAM of your Android Studio emulator (not that that will necessarily help in this particular situation) try this:

Go to Tools->Android->AVD Manager, there's something a like pencil to edit your AVD click on that, then in the pop-up window click Show Advanced Settings and there you can change the RAM size.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed bluestack which reduces your storage. AVD needs free space for running. Because it has to store a lot of things in the time of testing/running app on it. Without available storage how could it save data? you have to delete some files from your hard drive for making storage for the emulator